# TypeError: Type address[1] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type address[] memory

Tags: solidity

So I'm trying to call Comptroller's `function enterMarkets(address[] calldata cTokens) returns (uint[] memory)`. The problem that I have is if I call the function with my array of markets, it gives me the error, `TypeError: Type address[1] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type address[] memory`.

I understand that the function expects an address array of an undefined length, but every method I can think of to pass an array to the function gives me the same error. For example, the following methods return the same error:

```
address[] memory markets = [address(cdaitoken)];
comptroller.enterMarkets(markets);
```

```
comptroller.enterMarkets([address(cdaitoken)]);
```

Answer (score 17):

Solution if anyone's curious:

```
address[] memory markets = new address[](1)
markets[0] = address(cdaitoken)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for providing your answer! That's exactly what i have questions for too.